# How do I create arrays within a nested for loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create an array from this nested for loop

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++){
        $dis = $i + $j;
        createArr($dis, $i);
    }
    echoArr($i);
}
```

To do this I created a function called createArr() which receives $dis and the $i iterator.

```
$arr= array();

function createArr($dis, $i){
    $arr= 'arr'.$i;
    array_push($arr, $dis);
    return $arr;
}
```

I want $arr to be the name of the array in this example during the first iteration of the nested for loop $i = 0. Thus I want the name of the array to be `$arr0` with the array_push function pushing all the elements of $j while $i = 0 then to store into another array when the second iteration of $i when it starts at`$arr1` to push the new elements of this array within $j's iteration when $i = 1;

```
function echoArr($i){
    $arr= 'arr'.$i;
    return $arr;

}
```

this last function is to echo the finished array after an iteration of $i is done.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are expecting

```
$arr= 'arr'.$i;
array_push($arr, $dis);
```

to do, but array_push expects first parameter to be array, 
but as you can see $arr is a string.

Is this what you need?

```
$arr = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++){
        $dis = $i + $j;
        array_push($arr, createArr($dis, $i));
    }
    echoArr($i);
}

function createArr($dis, $i){
    return array('arr'.$i => $dis);
}

print_r($arr);

//prints: Array ( [0] => Array ( [arr0] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [arr0] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [arr0] => 2 ) [3] => Array ( [arr1] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [arr1] => 2 ) [5] => Array ( [arr1] => 3 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?
For the future pls describe what you would like to achieve so we can help you achieve it better.

Let me start with the first piece of code

You would like to echo the array. You are just echoing the column.
why build your own function to add something to an array?
and if you to do something with the return

$myarray[$i] = createArr($key,$value); //not a good solution, just for explaining.

Since I don't know what you like to achieve here an example of an array loop

$myarray = array();

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++){
        $dis = $i + $j;
        $myarray[$i][$j] = 'row:' . $i . ' column' . $j;
    }
}
var_dump($myarray);
```

and the dump

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'row:0 column0' (length=13)
      1 => string 'row:0 column1' (length=13)
      2 => string 'row:0 column2' (length=13)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'row:1 column0' (length=13)
      1 => string 'row:1 column1' (length=13)
      2 => string 'row:1 column2' (length=13)
```